# Beta Question Problem

Tags: beta-function

I was trying to understand a problem relating to the beta function.
In the middle of the solution, there is this line that confuses me, as I have no idea how the infinite summation simplifies to the natural logarithm.

$$\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(x\left(1-x\right)\right)^{\left(n-1\right)}}{2n}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\ln\left(1-x\left(1-x\right)\right)\left(x\left(1-x\right)\right)^{-1}dx$$

Comment: Do you know the Taylor series for $\ln(1-u)$?

Comment: @KennyWong Yes, but that has alternating signs (negative and positive), so I don't see how the author simplifies the integral using the Taylor series.

Comment: Sorry, I just fumbled, I think I get it.

Comment: @KennyWong Thanks for the help, I got it!!!